# R: how to find and extract values in a dataframe

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I have a character vector in R with 330000 values e.g.

amp184660
amp947
amp53303
amp364886
amp121615

and and a data frame like this:

[image]

I want to find each value from my character vector in first column of the data frame i.e. "Assay Name" and then output its corresponding chromosome position i.e "Chrom" into a new vector. I want to do this as quickly as possible as there are about 330k entries and doing this via grep over a loop will take about 12 hours to finish.

Any ideas?
Thanks
Jason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest `%in%`, which is likely to be faster than `merge`. Here's a toy example:

```
## Assume that "x" is your data.frame
set.seed(1)
x <- data.frame(Assay = sample(letters, 30, replace = TRUE), 
                Chrom = 4, ChromPos = rnorm(30))

## And that "y" is your vector you want to match
y <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")

## Here's how you can use %in%
x[x$Assay %in% y, ]
#    Assay Chrom   ChromPos
# 10     b     4  0.6198257
# 12     e     4 -0.1557955
# 24     d     4  1.1000254
# 27     a     4 -0.2533617

## And can also directly extract a specific column
x[x$Assay %in% y, "ChromPos"]
# [1]  0.6198257 -0.1557955  1.1000254 -0.2533617
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# assume your df called your_data_frame and vector called your_character_vector

vector_frame<-data.frame("Assay Name"=your_character_vector)
merge(vector_frame,your_data_frame,by="Assay Name")[,3]
```

note I changed the column notation from $Chrom to [,3] because I saw you wanted the third column and R will rename the column in the $ call e.g. to Chrom.Pos..bp. or something similar - if you type the $ and press TAB in the RStudio editor it'll give you the options

Comment: Thanks!. How do I save the new data frame after merge?

Comment: just put `new_df_name<-` in front of the merge call

Comment: and obviously if you want more columns in the new df, you can for instance do merge(vector_frame,your_data_frame,by="Assay Name")[,1:3]

Answer (score 0):

Just in case runtime is still a problem, using the `data.table` package is approx. 100x faster than `merge` and 50x faster than `%in%`:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table( yourDataFrame )
setkey( dt, Assay )
dt[ J(yourVector) ]
```